# Is there any command to retrieve result at second level query

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to describe this problem using exact technical phrases. But this is the scenario for the problem.

Below is my table which consists of 3 levels of users.
Normally, I can achieve my expected result by using loop in code.
I need to know is there a simple way to achieve this at database level.

```
    id| name     | level  | boss_id  |
    --|----------|--------|----------|  
    1 | User A   |   1    |  5       |
    2 | User B   |   1    |  5       |
    3 | User C   |   1    |  6       |
    4 | User D   |   1    |  6       |          
    5 | Leader A |   2    |  7       |
    6 | Leader B |   2    |  7       |
    7 | Boss A   |   3    |  0       |
```

When I look up for Boss A, I want to be able to list all users which are linked to leaders (Leader A & Leader B) attached to Boss A.
The result would be:

```
User A
User B
User C
User D
```

Comment: if they had the same boos_id it would be simple but how should a query know that id 0 is linked with 7 6 and 5 or is the only one boss?

Comment: there will be more boss at level 3 which are having another leaders (level 2) with their own users